# How to delete all files inside a directory except some extensions?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-search

I am doing a merge of some backups and those folders have user profile files.

I just need all `.mp3` or `.wav` or `.doc` or `.docx`.

I don't need photos, pictures and videos.

I want to search on my main folder all subfolders in that directory to deleta everything *except* `.mp3` or `.wav` or `.doc` or `.docx` files.

Any way? Could be a Batch file, script or basic command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method, it's an entry-level PowerShell script, to use it, you just have to open PowerShell by Win+R(press and hold Windows key then press R key) to bring up Run menu and type PowerShell and then press enter, then copy and paste the following codes (you have to replace the $path variable with the full path of your folder) and press enter:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Force -Recurse -Except *.mp3,*.wav,*.doc,*.docx).fullname | foreach {Remove-Item -path $_}
```

Sorry, I made a basic mistake, now it should be working.

Comment: When I tried this, I had to swap -Except, for -Exclude.  Worked fine then!

Answer (score 0):

In windows explorer simply (Ctrl+F) for invoking search folder for all files which not have the given extensions as follows:

`NOT *.mp3 NOT *.doc* NOT *.wav`

This is opposite search criterion to search for these files.

Then select all found items (Ctrl+A) and delete them (DEL) , as usually in Windows, probably pressing (Enter) to confirm that You want to sent them deep to trash can.